# Add my SQL Server database file to my application path to use it in different machines

Tags: sql-server, database

This is my first time with SQL Server 2014. I normally use Access database. 
My question is how can I move the `.mdf` file (database file) to my application path to use it on different machines?

I'm using this connection string in the `app.config` :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conn"
         connectionString="Server = DESKTOP-TP1616Q; Database=Exchange_DB; user Id=sa;Password=Password1;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

How can I change it to read from a `.mdf` file in the application folder(Debug) ?

My Question is how to change the connection string to make the application read from the moved mdf in the Debug folder, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to choose backup and move .mdf and .ldf file to which folder that you want.

```
RESTORE DATABASE DatabaseName FROM DISK='+QuotedStr(OpenDialog1.FileName)+' WITH MOVE ''Test'' TO '''+ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'copytest.mdf'' '+',MOVE ''Test_log'' TO '''+ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+'copytest.ldf''
```

Comment: I already moved the mdf and the ldf to the application file (Debug) but what im asking for , how to change the connection string to make the application read from the moved mdf , thank you

Comment: @Rabeeaqabaha,by that code you create database in sqlserver and then you should set  address of  connection string